# Structural damage because of air vent

Tags: walls, dryer, vent

I need to make an air vent for a tumble dryer hose on an external structural wall.

Is there any chance to compromise the wall structure because of the hole for the vent?

Should I add a structure such as a metal frame, etc?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So long as you're not removing a stud or part of a stud, you should be fine. Just punching a 4" hole through sheetrock, insulation, and the outside covering (brick, vinyl, aluminum, etc) will not compromise the structural integrity of the wall.

Comment: If you can get a 4.5" hole saw you'll have a nice clean hole. Many rental stores have them.

Comment: Be careful of where the hole is placed, which could allow unwanted sound, moisture, Fire rating, etc.

Comment: @LeeSam can you extend a bit on the fire retardant bit please?

Comment: @zom-pro If the wall is “within” a required setback, openings are not allowed, unless they are “protected”. Protected means the opening needs a fire damper in the opening.

Comment: @Lee Sam - That's a new one for me.  Setback from what?  The edge of the property line?  Is that part of the IBC, or is it a local reg?

Comment: @SteveSh Yes, the property line, or the overhang line, etc. , unless you build a fire wall. That fire wall must be protected with “fire resistive material “ , which gives the appropriate fire rating. That’s why if you cut a hole in that fire wall you’ll need to install a fire damper.

Comment: @Lee Sam - But many houses, especially those with vinyl siding do not have fire walls on the exterior.  What am I missing here?

Comment: @SteveSh Vinyl siding doesn’t mean the exterior wall is fire rated or not. If the exterior wall has gypsum sheathing on the exterior and fire rated gypsum board on the interior it’s fire rated. Or, it could have another sub-sheathing that meets a fire rating. You can place anything over the fire rated wall...like vinyl siding, etc.